alpha seems to not be working for tm_raster
No matter what I set alpha to I get completely opaque rasters. Running version 1.7-83
foo <- terra::rast(
  nrows=20, ncols=20,
  xmin=-88.4320615142538, xmax=-87.9239294737916,
  ymin=30.1444683138419, ymax=31.1732638929798,
  vals=1:400,
  crs="EPSG:4269"
)

tmap::tmap_options(basemaps="OpenStreetMap")

tmap::tmap_mode("view") # set mode to interactive plots

tmap::tm_shape(foo) + 
  tmap::tm_raster(alpha=0.2,
                  palette = "Blues",
                  colorNA=NULL,
                  title = "foo") 



If you think this is a bug, then the best way to resolve it would be to raise an issue on the tmap github site.

It has nothing with {terra}. Please update {tmap} package to newer version, there was a lot of changes in last year or so.
library(tmap)

tmap_options(basemap.server = c("OpenStreetMap"))
tmap_mode("view") # set mode to interactive plots


tm_shape(foo) + 
  tm_raster(col_alpha=0.4,
                  col.scale = tm_scale_categorical(n.max = 4, values = "brewer.blues",
                                                   value.na = "red"),
                  col.legend = tm_legend(title = "foo"))



packageVersion("tmap")
#> [1] '3.99.9002'

Created on 2024-11-18 with reprex v2.1.1.9000
